# Gmock encountered error on Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am new at using Google Mock and I encountered an error: "Error: Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(…)".

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. I followed this solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060980/uninteresting-mock-function-call-bla-expected-to-be-called-at-least-once-b) and I am still encountering this error.

Here is the sample code I am working on:

Orig Class

```
//orig.h
#include <stdio.h>

class Orig {
public:
    virtual ~Orig(){}
    virtual int this_func(uint8_t x, uint8_t* y, uint8_t z) = 0;
    virtual int that_func(uint8_t x, uint8_t* y, uint8_t z) = 0;
    virtual void those_func(int abc) = 0;
};
```

Mock Orig Class

```
//mock_orig.h
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "calling_class.h"

class MockOrig : public Orig {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD3(this_func, int(uint8_t x, uint8_t* y, uint8_t z));
    MOCK_METHOD3(that_func, int(uint8_t x, uint8_t* y, uint8_t z));
    MOCK_METHOD1(those_func, void(int abc));
};
```

Calling Class

```
//calling_class.h
#define MY_CONST1       0x01
#define MY_CONST2       0x02
#define X_CONST1        0x03
#define X_CONST2        0x04
#define SAMPLE_VALUE    (20)
#define TOTAL_VALUE     (100/SAMPLE_VALUE)

#include "orig.h"

class CallingClass {
public:
    explicit CallingClass(Orig * o) : mOrig(o){};
    void calling_func(void) {
        static int oldValue = 0;
        static uint16_t counter = 0;
        uint8_t buffer[2] = {0};
        int firstBit = 0;
        int secondBit = 0;

        if (0 == oldValue && (0 == mOrig->this_func(X_CONST1, buffer, 1))
        {
            secondBit = (int)(buffer[0] & MY_CONST2);
            firstBit = (int)(buffer[0] & MY_CONST1);
            if((oldValue != secondBit) && (0 != firstBit))
            {
                mOrig->those_func(secondBit);
                oldValue = secondBit;
                counter = TOTAL_VALUE;
            }
            return;
        }

        if (0 >= --counter && (0 == mOrig->this_func(X_CONST1, buffer, 1)))
        {
            uint8_t out = buffer[0] | MY_CONST2;
            mOrig->that_func(X_CONST2, &out, 1);
            oldValue = 0;
        }
        return;
    }

    private:
        Orig * mOrig;
}
```

Test Proper

```
//mock_orig.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <memory>

TEST(myTest, testMyFunction)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Orig> mO(new MockOrig);
    uint8_t buffer[1];
    EXPECT_CALL(*std::static_pointer_cast<MockOrig>(mO), this_func(X_CONST1, buffer, 1))
        .Times(1);
     CallingClass callerClass(mO.get());
     callerClass.calling_func();

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Can somebody please tell me what is still wrong with this? Any help/leads would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Google mock should have printed which arguments did not match the expectation, could you please post it here?

Comment: One thing I see right now: local variable `buffer` in `CallingClass::calling_func` is not the same as local variable `buffer`  in `TEST(myTest, testMyFunction)`. You should use proper matcher. You might check `EXPECT_CALL(*std::static_pointer_cast<MockOrig>(mO),  this_func(X_CONST1, _, 1))` to validate my observation